# Is it possible to ssh into amazon instance using jmeter

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have amazon instance and I want to ssh into the instance.
I have no idea about it, open for any thoughts.
Also, does it help if I use BeanShell scripting (just an idea), if so could you provide some doc or guide me into it?

Comment: Did you check this guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is. The easiest way is using [SSH Sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler) plugin.

1. Example Configuration:

   [image: SSH Sampler]
2. Example Result

   [image: SSH Sampler Result]
3. More information (if required): [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)